# Automate vi / nano editor for git commit --amend

Tags: python, c, git, shell

Basically I have to fetch a specific commit and then modify it's commit message. so after `cherrypick` I did `git commit --amend` and when editor`(nano/vi)` opens then added some text in between and save & exit.

I tried to modify `.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG` file through shell script but it didn't work. I'm able to modify the file but changes didn't reflect to git push. :(

So I want to open a file in `nano` editor then add few line in between of the file then save and exit

For nano Editor 
Step 1: save (WriteOut) `ctrl + o` and 
Step 2: press `Enter` then 
Step 3: Exit (Exit) `ctrl + x`

for vi editor 
Step 1: `:!wq` or `:x` or `shift + ZZ`  `<you know how to save and exit>`

I have tried many option like invoking `vi/nano editor` terminal through python script but didn't help :(. 
tried sending signal F2 and F3 for nano editor from shell script and c language didn't work.

How to automate this process of opening in terminal then write something and save & exit.

Please help me to get the solution.

**[[SOLUTION]]**
ex for vi editor

```
#addTextHelper.sh
#!/bin/bash
ex $1 <<EOEX
    :%s/$string_to_replace/$string_to_replace_with/g
    :x
EOEX

#addText.sh
GIT_EDITOR=./addText_Helper.sh git commit --amend
```

Comment: why don't you use the `-m` option to git commit at the command line instead

Comment: @wim As I mentioned that I have to modify some text in between of the message. Actually I'll look for specific tag in commit message and then find the tag and append some text, which is not possible by using -m option.

Comment: Yes you can I think, I'll add an answer ..

Comment: I simply want to append a particular message at a specific location, and then pushing it to gerrit. With -m it will amend the message for a commit id but i want to append the message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Point the `GIT_EDITOR` environment variable to a script that makes the necessary commit message changes. The script will get the path to a file with current commit message (and Git's help text) as the first argument.

Example script that uses ed to add a line after the first blank line:

```
#!/bin/sh

ed $1 <<EOT
/^$
a
Extra text goes here.
.
wq
EOT
```

Example invocation:

```
GIT_EDITOR=./patch-commit-message.sh git commit --amend
```